# Print out per each sublist items at time

Tags: python

So far after hours, I still cannot figure this out. Any help or anything that anyone can offer would be much appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

```
 stats.append({
                'rounds' : round_playing,
                'round' : [{'name' : str(list_players[i]['name']),
                            'score' : list_players[i]['score']
                           }]
                })
```

**list_players:**

```
list_players.append({'name': '',
             'score': 0})
```

**Print it out:**

```
for s in stats:
            print("*************************************")
            print("Round: " + str(s['rounds']))
            print("*************************************")
            for p in s['round']:
                print("@" + str(p['name'])
                    + "\nScore: " + str(p['score'])+ "\n")

        print("*********************")
```

**Currently:**

```
============================
Round 1
============================
Player1
Score: 11

============================
Round 1
============================
Player2
Score: 23
```

**Desired result:**

```
============================
Round 1
============================
Player1
Score: 11

Player2
Score: 23

============================
Round 2
============================
Player1
Score: 55

Player2
Score: 7
```

Someone suggested something like this:

```
def buildList(p):
    for i in range(len(p)): 
        list_players.append({'name': '', 'score': 0})
```

Not sure.

Comment: data pointed by `round` is always a 1-item list. You're basically dispatching the players into each dict entry, not gathering them.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't run, as is, and the data in your question isn't sufficient to produce the sample output.  For the best chance at decent help, please create and post a decent [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read this important link to learn the details.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, how should I gather them??

Comment: You're going to want to change the way `list_players` is structured so that it is a list of lists of dictionaries, each sublist corresponding to the players in a round and their scores

Comment: at some point you have to do `s['round'].append()` or your list will have 1-size. Your data structure seems very complex.

Comment: Based on my assumptions, the problem is that you put each player into `stats`, then you print the "Round n" header for each item in `stats`.  You'll need to fix your data model (best solution), or make your code much more complicated to deal with the data model you have (determining when it has found a new round to print the header).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre So basically, I should append(list) under a new list? I don't fully understand. Any example or answer with code would make this easier. Much appreciated. Thx.

Comment: @JohnSmith you only really need one data structure here.  Go back to the code where you build `list_players` and change it so that it has all the information you need

Comment: @PatrickHaugh, see my edit. However, I am not sure.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, how do you actually gather them? Please note, I haven't programmed much Python before. If this would be some other language I would easily have solved it.

Comment: can you include code that can be used to recreate the list that you are using?

Comment: What's your input information? Can you control it or redefine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** - Don't append single player entries to `stats`. Instead, append the complete data (all the players) for each round.

---

The issue in your code is the data structure being used which is making it difficult to print the data in a correct manner. As mentioned in the comments, the length of  the `rounds` value in each element of `stats` is always `1`, due to which you are getting such an output.

While it's okay to use such a data structure for `stats`, it's probably not the best idea given the format you wish to print your data in. It's better to **collect all the data corresponding to a single round**. So the idea in my answer is to bring all data corresponding to a single round collected into a single element of `stats`.

**Assumption** - I'll make an assumption that `list_players` is updated dynamically with new data as you are building `stats`.

**Building** `list_players` - Keep it as it is, since you intend to run over the whole list.

**Building** `stats` - In case your round numbers are always starting from `1` and grow sequentially, you can simply make a list where index `i` represents round `i+1`. If you have more complicated round names, you can **use a dictionary**, with the key being the round number, as this will allow easy access to the stats of a particular round number.

Also, you can directly copy `list_players` instead of running a loop across it, as you are building an identical data stucture.

With a list,

```
for round in range(0, total_rounds):
    # Modify scores in `list_players` correctly
    # You have to copy the whole list, since `list_players` will
    # change over the course loop
    stats.append(list_players[:])
```

With a dictionary,

```
stats = {}
for round in round_numbers:
    # Modify scores of `list_players` correctly
    # Again, make sure you copy the list as it's dynamic
    stats[round] = list_players[:]
```

**Printing the result** -

If `stats` is kept as a list, I've used the [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function.

```
for index, round in enumerate(stats):
    # Always use 4 space indentation
    print("*************************************")
    print("Round: " + str(index+1)
    print("*************************************")
    for p in round:
        print("@" + str(p['name']) +
              "\nScore: " + str(p['score'])+ "\n")
        print("*********************")
```

With a dictionary,

```
for key, value in stats.iteritems():
    # Always use 4 space indentation
    print("*************************************")
    print("Round: " + str(key)
    print("*************************************")
    for p in value:
        print("@" + str(p['name']) +
              "\nScore: " + str(p['score'])+ "\n")
        print("*********************")
```